# OCaml garbage collect phantom types

Tags: c, garbage-collection, ocaml

Suppose, I have a C library interfaced with OCaml:

```
  type _npnum;;

  external _create_zero : int -> int -> _npnum = "ocaml_tnp_number_create_zero" ;;

  external _delete : _npnum -> unit = "ocaml_tnp_number_delete" ;;
```

The C-library allocates the objects and returns them via OCaml's Int32/64 representations (I "stole" that from ctypes).

But I actually want OCaml to garbage collect these objects, so how do I tell the compiler/runtime that `_delete` shall be used to clean up an `_npnum` ?

I tried to wrap the whole thing into a record and used the finalizer functions from Core, but that is a unwanted dependency and also does only work as long as noone copies a record. I guess there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard library there is [Gc.finalise](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/libref/Gc.html#VALfinalise) and if your data type is abstract nobody should be able to copy it  in most cases (however as Pascal rightly pointed below there are a few corner cases).

If you really want to handle these corner cases use a [custom block](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/intfc.html#sec449) on the C size to wrap the pointer and expose this as an abstract type. This will allow you to attach a custom finalizer, handle marshaling correctly and `Weak.get_copy` won't try to copy it.

Comment: Abstract objects can be copied with `Weak.get_copy` and various unmarshaling functions. I have no idea how `Gc.finalise` combines with `Weak.get_copy`.

Comment: Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/byterun/weak.c) it doesn't do anything particular about it. But since it does a shallow copy you should be able to get around by doing e.g. `type wrap = { v : _npnum }` (the finalized value) `type t = { wrap : wrap }` and expose `t`.

Comment: Why should noone be able to copy my abstract data type? When I expose it, a surely can write a function that takes an `_npnum` and passes it to two or more other functions, hence copy it?

Comment: You are not passing copies of the values your are passing the value itself.

Comment: I get that, but how does the GC distunguish ;)? If I pass a phantom-type value, when does the GC track its usage? Surely it doesn't do, when I pass it as an int, but how about an Int32?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "phantom-type value". Phantom types have nothing to do with values, they are typing constraint on the type parameter of an abstract data type (and type parameter that is not used in the actual definition of the data type). If you want to use Gc.finalise  you need to do it on a heap-allocated value (see the linked doc to understand what it means). If you use a custom block you will have a heap allocated value. Those values are tracked by the gc.

Comment: Btw you should change the title of your question as it really has nothing to do with phantom types. A better title would be something like "garbage collecting C allocated values".